# How can one use Input as convolution's filters in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a neural network, composed of many layers. I want to add a convolution layer to the network. But for my specific use, I want the convolution network to convolve the previous layer's output with unique filters, rather than studying them dynamically. The filters come from input layer, as I inject them during the fitting process.

The problem I encountered, is that `tf.keras.Conv2D` won't work with `InputLayer` output as a filter, as it requires a tensor (like `tf.constant`).

My code can be simplified to this,

```
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,1000,1))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((2000,2000,1))

# example for pipeline
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (10,10), padding='same')(x2)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (10,10), padding='same')(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (10,10), padding='same')(y)

z = my_layer()([y,x1])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x1,x2], outputs=z)
```

where,

```
class my_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
   def __init__(self):
      super(my_layer, self).__init__()

   def call(self, inputs):
      return tf.nn.conv2d(inputs[0], inputs[1], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

The received error:

```
ValueError: Depth of input (1) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (1000) ...
```

I wish to ask if there is a walk-around this problem.

Comment: It could be better if you share your code, and what you have done so far. Otherwise, it will be a little hard to understand what you need and describe what you should do in your case.

Comment: Re-edited. The error is received as variable $x1$ is a Input Tensor and not Kernel Tensor, but I don't recall a trick how to convert between the two. They are two different beasts in Tensorflow world.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique" in "I want the convolution network to convolve the previous layer's output with unique filters, rather than studying them dynamically"

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui I want the filters to come from the input layer, i.e. to be injected during the optimization stage. In my case, every data sample has it is own unique filter. When looking at the code given, x2 represents the 'data sample' and x1 is the matching filter.

Comment: @tnt1674 You mean filters are part of the dataset ?

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui True.

Comment: Your diagnosis of the problem is completely incorrect, the shapes of your filters are not right, it has nothing to do with a tf.constant, read the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d to find the correct shapes.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy The error recieved is indeed dimensions misa-match error. But it so, because the input should be [batch size, width, height, in channel], and the filter should be [width, height, in channels, out channels]. Since my filters come from input, i.e. [batch, width, height, out channels], it doesn't fit the requirement. Hence, I asked how one can walkaround the batch-dimension problem. I tried making tf.constant from copy of the input layer but failed. Seems as calculating the covlution with simple aretmatic operators is the only way.

Comment: You will face the same problem if you compute convolution manually, this constraint is part of the convolution operation, there is no workaround, your only option is to change the shape of the filters so they can be used with convolution.

Comment: Also the batch dimension has nothing to do here, you again misinterpreted the error message.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The error received is not the underlying problem in my case. Tensorflow print out error because indeed my filter shape doesn't meet tf.nn.conv2d requirements. But the underlying problem is that InputLayer can't be transferred to the required shape as it seemed. My filter-input is of shape [?,1,1000,1], and can't be converted to [filter width, filter height, in channels, out channels] because of the batch dimension '?'. I can't reshape the InputLayer to be a kernel-tensor or even make a copy of it. And this is what I am struggling with. Even if my filter be [?,1,1,1], it won't work.